# Sparkle-project setup

Tags: sparkle

I'm trying to implement Sparkle into my macOS project using cocoapod.
But when following the documentation I seem to have a problem creating the public .pem file.

Command used in Terminal;

```
.ssh $ ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 1024
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/jorgen/.ssh/id_dsa): dsa
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in dsa.
Your public key has been saved in dsa.pub.
```

According to the documentation I should have a file called dsa_pub.pem but all I end up with is dsa.pub

If anyone has a couple of minutes to give me simple step-by-step instructions how to set this up, I would be immensely appreciative.
I was going to use a DropBox folder as the https:// address.  I archive the app into a .app as far as I can understand, I would zip this and put it in the DB folder?  What else goes in there?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download sparkle: https://sparkle-project.org
2. go to the `bin` folder inside the archive
3. open that folder in `Terminal` (drag and drop from folder)
4. call `./generate_keys` to generate `dsa_priv.pem` and `dsa_prb.pem` in the same folder